# StackPane setBackground

Tags: java, javafx

here is my code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class NotesApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.setPrefSize(700,700);

        StackPane leftPane = new StackPane();
        leftPane.setPrefSize(100, 700);
        Button button = new Button("Button 1");
        leftPane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.YELLOW, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        leftPane.getChildren().add(button);
        leftPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

        StackPane rightPane = new StackPane();
        rightPane.setPrefSize(200,700);
        Button button1 = new Button("Button 2");
        rightPane.getChildren().add(button1);
        rightPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

        root.getChildren().addAll(leftPane, rightPane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have a class with a root StackPane and with another two StackPanes(leftPane and rightPane) inside the root StackPane. I want to set the background color of only the leftPane to yellow but the result is that the whole window gets the yellow background, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A `StackPane` will resize its children to fill _all available space_, up to their _max size_. On top of that, a `StackPane` will center its children by default, so the separation of "left" and "right" does not quite make sense. Would using an `HBox` for your root instead work for what you're trying to do? Or `BorderPane`? Or a `SplitPane`?

Comment: Well, I'm fairly new to javafx so the whole system of VBox, HBox, StackPane etc is something I'm trying to learn on the go. What I want to do is to make the left side(maybe 20% width) and the right side(maybe 20% width) of the window contain a few buttons and texts, and then sometime later add something to the middle.

Comment: That sounds like a good use case for `BorderPane` ([Javadoc](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html)). Also, here's a [tutorial on layouts in general](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/index.html) and [on BorderPane specifically](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#sthref9).

Comment: Currently looking into it, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a particular reason to use StackPane as root, you could use AnchorPane. You could set 3 side anchors for your left and right StackPanes and bind your Stackpanes's width with your roots width, so if you resize your window your stackpanes going to adapt to it

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class NotesApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane(); // Changed stackpane to anchor pane
        root.setPrefSize(700,700);

        StackPane leftPane = new StackPane();
        leftPane.minWidthProperty().bind(root.widthProperty().divide(2)); // Binding leftPane's width with the half of your root

        Button button = new Button("Button 1");
        leftPane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.YELLOW, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        leftPane.getChildren().add(button);
        leftPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

        StackPane rightPane = new StackPane();
        rightPane.minWidthProperty().bind(root.widthProperty().divide(2)); // Binding rightPane's width with the half of your root

        Button button1 = new Button("Button 2");
        rightPane.getChildren().add(button1);
        rightPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
        rightPane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.RED, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));

        root.getChildren().addAll(leftPane, rightPane);

        // Setting the anchors 
        root.setLeftAnchor(leftPane, 0.0);
        root.setTopAnchor(leftPane, 0.0);
        root.setBottomAnchor(leftPane, 0.0);

        root.setRightAnchor(rightPane, 0.0);
        root.setTopAnchor(rightPane, 0.0);
        root.setBottomAnchor(rightPane, 0.0);


        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```